# Grep tool for XML

Tags: automation, grep, xml, regex

I am looking for a good tool to perform grep-like operations on XML - for example, extract certain attributes only.

`Grep` itself can't handle it - any DFA-equivalent tool can handle only non recursive matches, and mine may be recursive.

I have tried [xgrep](http://wohlberg.net/public/software/xml/xgrep/), but it is quite unstable, and I want a stable and reliable tool.

Any recommendations?

**EDIT: I prefer open source tools that work well under Linux.**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[XMLStarlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLStarlet) (Wikipedia) is a command line tool which comes close to `grep`. 
It is open source software (MIT license) and works well on Linux and Windows.

[The XMLStarlet website](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net) describes it as follows.

> XMLStarlet is a set of command line
> utilities (tools) which can be used to
> transform, query, validate, and edit
> XML documents and files using simple
> set of shell commands in similar way
> it is done for plain text files using
> UNIX grep, sed, awk, diff, patch,
> join, etc commands.

The Debian/Ubuntu package is named `xmlstarlet`.
**But beware:** Contrary to what the manpage says, the binary is named `xmlstarlet` in Debian/Ubuntu and not `xml`.

There are also Windows binaries on SourceForge.

For a nice little introduction, see IBM's [Start working with XMLStarlet](https://web.archive.org/web/20150511173455/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-starlet/index.html) (now via archive.org).

Comment: Remove the trailing slash from the first link.

Comment: I can't get it to work... It never matches on any xpath except '/' (the whole document), which is pretty worthless :(

Comment: @HendyIrawan - Are you sure it's not how you're trying to use xpath? (Like your XML has a default namespace that you're not accounting for?)

Comment: I tried to clone it, but it seems that the repository is broken.

Answer (score 5):

The [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp) syntax in various languages is best for finding things in xml. In fact [one of the tools](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/tools/xml_grep/xml_grep) recommended by the makers of xgrep is basically a Perl XML parser that accepts XPath input.

Answer (score 5):

A tool that works under Linux is *xml_grep*. It fully understands XML and is not a line-by-line tool.

*xml_grep* is included as a *stand-alone* tool in the [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.52/Twig.pm) package. The grepping functionality is quite powerful as it supports [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) specifications.

Sample command-line (extracting posts edited after the middle of February from the [triology Data Dump](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/creative-commons-data-dump-mar-10/)):

```
xml_grep -p --cond="row[@LastEditDate>'2010-02-14']"  posts.xml  > lateEditedPosts.xml
```

---

Installation is easy. Either

- `sudo cpan -i "XML::Twig"`, as described in the xml_grep cookbook referenced below.

or

- Download http://xmltwig.org/xmltwig/XML-Twig-3.34.tar.gz or http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/M/MI/MIROD/XML-Twig-3.34.tar.gz. E.g.
  `wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/M/MI/MIROD/XML-Twig-3.34.tar.gz`
- Extract: `gunzip XML-Twig-3.34.tar.gz; tar -xvf XML-Twig-3.34.tar`
- Go to into folder: `cd XML-Twig-3.34`
- Install: `perl Makefile.PL -y`. Then
  `make`, `make test` and `sudo make install`.

---

More information:

The best introduction I have found for *xml_grep* is *[xml_grep cookbook](http://thebogles.com/blog/2009/08/xml_grep-cookbook/)*, about two pages. Other:

- [Man page for xml_grep](http://xmltwig.org/xmltwig/tools/xml_grep/xml_grep.html).
- [Real home page](http://www.xmltwig.org/xmltwig/) for XML::Twig.

Comment: I have fixed a broken link, but the triology Data Dump link is also broken. I will see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise NOT to use a grep-like tool on XML, but use a library to parse XML in stead.
What exactly do you need it for? Any programming language? I think the .NET built-in XML parser would fit the job easily if you're willing to write a program for it though.

**Update**: for Linux, a well known XML parser library is [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/).

Answer (score -1):

[XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/simpledownload2c.html?gclid=CJnXtbDMjJwCFQQupAodPGivYw) is an amazing tool, if a bit spendy.