# Is there a native tool for parsing xml files available on RedHat?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, xml

Are there any utilities similar to xpath for parsing XML files that would be natively available on a RedHat server?

Similar questions have been answered [elsewhere](https://superuser.com/questions/18466/grep-tool-for-xml), but none of the tools listed are on the server.

*update:* [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) is installed, and `man xmllint` indicates that it can parse xml files, but it is not clear that this gives me the ability to extract a string from a specific node.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `xmllint` and the `--xpath` option:

```
<xml>
  <hello>world!</hello>
</xml>

$ xmllint --xpath '//hello/text()'
world!
```

Comment: Too bad that the "--xpath" option is only available on RedHat 7, which was not around when this question was posted.

Comment: Workaround for earlier versions of xmllint: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38199367/185196

Answer (score 5):

If, given this XML

```
$ cat a.xml
<a>
  <b>Hello</b>
  <b>World</b>
</a>
```

You want to be able to do

```
$ ./xpath //a/b a.xml
Hello
World
```

then you could just cut & paste this:

```
$ cat xpath
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $document = $parser->parse_file($ARGV[1]);
my @nodes = $document->findnodes($ARGV[0]);
for my $node (@nodes) {
  print $node->textContent, "\n";
}
```

You should be able to install the XML::LibXML module using `perl -MCPAN -e 'install XML::LibXML'`

Comment: Or just `yum install 'perl(XML::LibXML)'`.

Answer (score 4):

[XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) is in [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

Answer (score 4):

xsltproc (command line interface to libxslt) is always available on RHEL.
usage: xsltproc xsl_stylesheet xml_file.

Answer (score 0):

On RHEL 7

```
yum install libxml2
```

gives you

```
xmllint
```

and it can parse XML files

```
# xmllint 
Usage : xmllint [options] XMLfiles ...
        Parse the XML files and output the result of the parsing
```